# Stack implemented using a single linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel, stack, c99

I am studying data structures and I have implemented a stack using a linked list.

**stack.h**

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#include <stdbool.h>

typedef char StackElement;

typedef struct stack_CDT *Stack;

Stack stack_init();

void stack_destroy(Stack s);

bool stack_is_empty(Stack s);

void stack_push(Stack s, StackElement elem);

StackElement stack_pop(Stack s);

#endif
```

**stack.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "stack.h"

typedef struct node {
    StackElement data;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

Node *node_create(StackElement data)
{
    Node *new = malloc(sizeof *new);
    new->data = data;
    new->next = NULL;
    return new;
}

void node_insert(Node **node_ref, Node *new)
{
    if (new == NULL)
        return;

    new->next = *node_ref;
    *node_ref = new;
}

void node_delete(Node **node_ref)
{
    if (*node_ref == NULL)
        return;

    Node *next = (*node_ref)->next;
    free(*node_ref);
    *node_ref = next;
}

void list_delete(Node **head_ref)
{
    while ((*head_ref) != NULL)
        node_delete(head_ref);
}

typedef struct stack_CDT {
    Node *top;
} StackCDT;

StackCDT *stack_init()
{
    StackCDT *new = malloc(sizeof *new);
    new->top = NULL;
    return new;
}

void stack_destroy(StackCDT *s)
{
    list_delete(&(s->top));
    free(s);
}

bool stack_is_empty(StackCDT *s)
{
    return s->top == NULL;
}

void stack_push(StackCDT *s, StackElement elem)
{
    Node *new = node_create(elem);
    node_insert(&(s->top), new);
}

StackElement stack_pop(StackCDT *s)
{
    if (stack_is_empty(s)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't pop element from stack, stack is empty.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    StackElement elem = s->top->data;
    node_delete(&(s->top));
    return elem;
}
```

**stacktest.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "stack.h"

#define MAX_STR_LEN 100

void stacktest()
{
    printf("Enter a string(not more than %d characters): ", MAX_STR_LEN);
    char input[MAX_STR_LEN + 1];    
    fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);
    char *pos;
    if ((pos = strchr(input, '\n')) != NULL)
        *pos = '\0';

    Stack stack = stack_init();
    for (char *c = input; *c; c++)
        stack_push(stack, *c);

    printf("Popped characters are: ");
    while (!stack_is_empty(stack))
        printf("%c", stack_pop(stack));
    printf("\n");

    stack_destroy(stack);
}

int main()
{
    stacktest();
    return 0;
}
```

Is my implementation all right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally looks good. Few comments:

- `Node` is not used by the client; it is a stack implementation detail, so `node_create`, `node_insert` and `node_delete` should be `static`.
- I prefer function returning results rather than `void` modifying its argument. Consider

  ```
  Node * node_insert(Node * ref, Node * new);
  Node * node_delete(Node * ref);
  ```

  It removes one level of indirection, and simplifies the implementation.
- An utility function such as `stack_pop` shall not print anything. In any case, it shall convey the error condition to the caller (an unconditional `exit` is a bit harsh). Consider setting `errno`, for example.

Comment: Well, an unconditional `abort()` on encountering an "impossible" situation, or violation of the contract, is the only useful thing. Whether poping an empty stack is a logic error, and should be treated as such? Yes! Assert in debug-mode, ignore in release-mode: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back

Comment: @Deduplicator No. Even __NO__. `assert` is fine in the application, and is absolutely unsuitable in a library code. The library lacks the context, and has no right to impose a policy. The only thing it may (and shall) do is to inform the caller.

Comment: Say that to the standard committee: If you violate basic preconditions, it's on your head. Hopefully, it leads to a fast crash. Debug-mode makes sure of that, as far as reasonably feasible. Also, remember that unexercised code is broken code, and how do you want to check reasonable behavior on logic-error, when you weed them out the moment you first trigger them?

Answer (score 4):

No, your implementation is broken:

You forgot to check whether allocation succeeded.

---

Reviewing your code, you are going way overboard following the "small methods"-mantra in your library-code:

While the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) means every function should do one thing, and only one thing, the size of each task should be properly chosen.

Too little, and the function isn't a useful abstraction, using, writing and remembering it takes more effort than it saves.
(The performance-cost may be negligible (or even non-existent), if it is inlined. Consider marking it `static` to promote inlining and avoid exporting.)

Too much, and reusability and composability suffer.

---

Header:

1. I would avoid a typedef for the element-type. What does it buy you?
2. Using an opaque pointer is a good idea allowing you to replace the implementation with something more performant later. So, well done there.
3. Consider leaving the parameter-name out of the declaration when it doesn't make it more descriptive.
4. You should add a variation on `stack_push` which signals success, so a caller can opt in to handling failure gracefully:

   ```
   bool stack_tryPush(Stack, StackElement);
   ```
5. Some more useful additions:

   ```
   StackElement stack_peek(Stack);
   StackElement stack_replace(Stack, StackElement);
   ```

Sourcefile:

6. You should re-order your includes: Always include the header you are implementing first, then all other headers, sorted for consistency (use the IDE's sorting-macro).
   That way, you will know that your header is self-sufficient and you didn't forget a crucial dependency.
7. There's `abort()` for abnormal termination. Consider writing a helper-function if you need to output an error-message and abort in multiple places:

   ```
   static void die(const char* message);
   ```
8. All your internal functions should not have external linkage, for performance and correctness reasons: Mark them `inline`.
9. Putting `next` first is more common, and possibly slightly more efficient. Also, for a single value `value` is more idiomatic than `data`.
10. Is there any reason why your typedef-name and struct-tag aren't *quite* equal? That's ittitating.
11. `node_create` is a waste: It's literally more work to read, write, and use it than leaving the single use inline.
    As a rule of thumb, extracting 2 lines into their own function is a net loss of readability. Exceptons are often-used pieces of code.

    Actually, that can be generalized to all your internal functions, with the possible exception of `node_delete`, which is marginal.
12. [There are](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15515/using-assertions-versus-throwing-exceptions) two [kinds of](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/116576/how-can-i-improve-my-error-checking-and-handling) precondition-checks:

    1. Sanity checks, verifying that the programs logic is sane. These are normally disabled in a release build for performance reasons, and use `assert()`.
    2. Tests of untrusted input. How far you can/should/must trust an API's user must be decided in each case. It's your task as API-designer to decide how much you should penalize your users to catch egregious abuse even in release-mode, and whether there's also a debug-mode.
       But there's no excuse for making your internal helper-functions re-assert preconditions even in release-mode.
13. As you are using C99 (see `<stdbool.h>`), you can use compound-literals to set all members of a struct-type comfortably even after initialization.

    ```
    void stack_push(StackCDT *s, StackElement value)
    {
        Node *new = malloc(sizeof *new);
        *new = (Node){s->top, value};
        if(!new) die("Failed to allocate a new node.");
        s->top = new;
    }
    ```

Testprogram:

14. `return 0;` is implicit in `main` since C99.
15. Any reason for extracting your *whole* `main` into a different function?

Comment: I used typedef for the stack element to make the stack generic. If I want to change the type of the stack element, then I can just change the typedef in the header file

Comment: Well, that's in itself a good idea. Though you know you are fighting the language there, and you can only ever have one variety of your stack in any program? C++ solves that with templates...