# Postfix evaluation using a stack in c

Tags: c, stack, math-expression-eval, c99

I have written a program to evaluate a postfix expression using a stack. I had my stack implementation using a linked list reviewed [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/110377/stack-implemented-using-a-single-linked-list), so I am only including the header file here.

I have taken the postfix expression in form of a string where the operators and operands are delimited by spaces and have used a sentinel at the end to mark the end of the expression.

stack.h

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

#include <stdbool.h>

typedef int StackElement;

typedef struct stack_CDT *Stack;

Stack stack_init();

void stack_destroy(Stack s);

bool stack_is_empty(Stack s);

void stack_push(Stack s, StackElement elem);

StackElement stack_pop(Stack s);

#endif
```

eval_postfix.h

```
#ifndef EVAL_POSTFIX_H
#define EVAL_POSTFIX_H

// space is the delimiter between the different tokens

extern const char *sentinel;

int eval_postfix(char *exp);

#endif
```

eval_postfix.c

```
#include "eval_postfix.h"
#include "stack.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_TOKEN_LEN 25

const char *sentinel = "$";

static char *get_token(char *token, char *exp, int idx)
{
    sscanf(exp + idx, "%s", token);
    return token;
}

static bool is_operator(char *token)
{
    return (strcmp(token, "/") == 0 || strcmp(token, "*") == 0 ||
            strcmp(token, "%") == 0 || strcmp(token, "+") == 0 ||
            strcmp(token, "-") == 0);
}

static int eval(int a, int b, char *op)
{
    if (strcmp(op, "/") == 0)
        return a / b;
    if (strcmp(op, "*") == 0)
        return a * b;
    if (strcmp(op, "%") == 0)
        return a % b;
    if (strcmp(op, "+") == 0)
        return a + b;
    if (strcmp(op, "-") == 0)
        return a - b;

    return 0;
}

int eval_postfix(char *exp)
{
    Stack s = stack_init();
    char token[MAX_TOKEN_LEN + 1];
    int i = 0;
    while (strcmp(get_token(token, exp, i), sentinel) != 0) {
        if (is_operator(token)) {
            int operand1 = stack_pop(s);
            int operand2 = stack_pop(s);
            stack_push(s, eval(operand2, operand1, token));
        } else {
            stack_push(s, (int)strtol(token, NULL, 0));
        }

        i += strlen(token) + 1; // one extra for the space
    }

    int res = stack_pop(s);
    stack_destroy(s);
    return res;
}
```

test.c

```
#include "eval_postfix.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_EXPRESSION_LEN 100

int main()
{
    printf("Enter postfix expression(no more than %d characters): ",
            MAX_EXPRESSION_LEN);
    char exp[MAX_EXPRESSION_LEN + 3];
    fgets(exp, sizeof exp, stdin);
    char *pos;
    if ((pos = strchr(exp, '\n')) != NULL)
        *pos = '\0';
    strcat(strcat(exp, " "), sentinel);

    printf("Result = %d\n", eval_postfix(exp));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Optimize strcmp chains

Some of your functions use `strcmp()` repeatedly.  You could make those functions faster by eliminating the multiple calls to `strcmp()` and using switch statements instead.  This function:

> ```
> static bool is_operator(char *token)
> {
>     return (strcmp(token, "/") == 0 || strcmp(token, "*") == 0 ||
>             strcmp(token, "%") == 0 || strcmp(token, "+") == 0 ||
>             strcmp(token, "-") == 0);
> }
> ```

would become:

```
static bool is_operator(const char *token)
{
    if (token[1] != '\0')
        return false;

    switch (token[0]) {
        case '/':
        case '*':
        case '%':
        case '+':
        case '-':
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

This function:

> ```
> static int eval(int a, int b, char *op)
> {
>     if (strcmp(op, "/") == 0)
>         return a / b;
>     if (strcmp(op, "*") == 0)
>         return a * b;
>     if (strcmp(op, "%") == 0)
>         return a % b;
>     if (strcmp(op, "+") == 0)
>         return a + b;
>     if (strcmp(op, "-") == 0)
>         return a - b;
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

could become:

```
static int eval(int a, int b, const char *op)
{
    switch (*op) {
        case '/':
            return a / b;
        case '*':
            return a * b;
        case '%':
            return a % b;
        case '+':
            return a + b;
        case '-':
            return a - b;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Notice I also added a `const` to your string arguments because they aren't modified by your functions.

## Confusing variable names

This code confused me a little:

> ```
>         int operand1 = stack_pop(s);
>         int operand2 = stack_pop(s);
>         stack_push(s, eval(operand2, operand1, token));
> ```

Here, `operand1` is actually the second operand, and `operand2` is actually the first operand, as you can see from the call to `eval()`.  I would have rewritten it like this, because otherwise it would get confusing if someone were stepping through it with a debugger and examining variable values:

```
        int operand2 = stack_pop(s);
        int operand1 = stack_pop(s);
        stack_push(s, eval(operand1, operand2, token));
```